# Deliver dummy image for not existing files in Apache

Tags: image, apache

We are developing web shops that are based on a lot of images.

On our local test system we do not have those images for performance reasons.

No when I open a webpage, logs and firebug are cluttered by a lot of 404 errors.

How can I configure Apache to just deliver a dummy image for cases where the image does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a error document (more in the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#errordocument)):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
```

From your `error404.php` you can use `getenv(“REQUEST_URI”)` to get the name of the requested page. If it's a image you push out your dummy image. Otherwise you show your normal error page.

Comment: Cool Idea. Do you know if I can remove the 404 Header in my error404.php ? My main reason for this whole thing is to remove 404 errors for images from Firebug that are not important for me.

Comment: Maybe you can make a redirect first. That could remove the error. Or maybe `header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");` overwrites the header?